# Using re module in Python to substitute all punctuations in two strings to compare them?

Tags: python, python-re

```
import re
def compare_strings(string1, string2):
  #Convert both strings to lowercase 
  #and remove leading and trailing blanks
  string1 = string1.lower().strip()
  string2 = string2.lower().strip()

  #Ignore punctuation
  punctuation = r"[.?!,;:-']"
  string1 = re.sub(punctuation, r"", string1)
  string2 = re.sub(punctuation, r"", string2)

  return string1 == string2

print(compare_strings("Have a Great Day!", "Have a great day?")) # Should be True
print(compare_strings("It's raining again.", "its raining, again")) # Should be True
print(compare_strings("Learn to count: 1, 2, 3.", "Learn to count: one, two, three.")) # Should be False
print(compare_strings("They found some body.", "They found somebody.")) # Should be False
```

The function above is removes trailing space, all punctuations from two strings and then it uses the .lower() function to remove nay capitalizations.

The purpose of the function is to compare the content matter in two given strings and return True if they match or False if they don't match. There is a mistake in here which I cannot spot.

Comment: Put the hyphen at the beginning of the punctuation characters, otherwise you might get a bad-character-range error. The hyphen is used to specify ranges of characters (like `a-z`), so it needs special handling.

Comment: The last example is great!

Answer (score 2):

Just escape the `-` symbol. `r"[.?!,;:\-']"` should work. You should consider writing your regex in a validator ex. [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Answer (score 1):

Since the question seems to be about this specific case, I'll provide an alternative approach.

```
for ch in ".?!,;:-'": 
    string.replace(ch,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def compare_strings(string1, string2):
  #Convert both strings to lowercase 
  #and remove leading and trailing blanks
  string1 = string1.lower().strip()
  string2 = string2.lower().strip()

  #Ignore punctuation
  punctuation = r"[.?!,;:'-]" 
  string1 = re.sub(punctuation, r"", string1)
  string2 = re.sub(punctuation, r"", string2)

      
  return string1 == string2

print(compare_strings("Have a Great Day!", "Have a great day?")) # True
print(compare_strings("It's raining again.", "its raining, again")) # True
print(compare_strings("Learn to count: 1, 2, 3.", "Learn to count: one, two, three.")) # False
print(compare_strings("They found some body.", "They found somebody.")) # False
```

This is the solution to this problem : place "-" at the end in punctuation ie
earlier the code was :

```
punctuation = r"[.?!,;:-']"
```

now :

```
punctuation = r"[.?!,;:'-]"
```

as , for this [.?!,;:-']

- -Character range is out of order

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def compare_strings(string1, string2):
    #Convert both strings to lowercase
    #and remove leading and trailing blanks
    string1 = string1.lower().strip()
    string2 = string2.lower().strip()

    #Ignore punctuation
    punctuation = r"[.?!,;:\-']"
    string1 = re.sub(punctuation, r"", string1)
    string2 = re.sub(punctuation, r"", string2)

    #DEBUG CODE GOES HERE
    print(string1, "==", string2)

    return string1 == string2

print(compare_strings("Have a Great Day!", "Have a great day?")) # True
print(compare_strings("It's raining again.", "its raining, again")) # True
print(compare_strings("Learn to count: 1, 2, 3.", "Learn to count: one, two, three.")) # False
print(compare_strings("They found some body.", "They found somebody.")) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

The '-' symbol must go after the " ' " symbol in "punctuation = r"[.?!,;:-']"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).